# Excel, Creating sum, every 144 values in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have an excel file over some years with 10min values [A2;A181441].

I want to SUM every row of 144 values into [C2;C1261].

Looking forward to your answers!

edit: Thanks @Rajesh S for update: Row of 144 values not every 144th value.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you want to Sum every 144 row in huge range?

Comment: Yes a row of 144, not 144th

Comment: you mean bunch of 144 rows!

Comment: ,, do you have values in group like City of Region,, like Col A has City name (same city from 1 to 144) and Column B has number to SUM,, or better share some sample data with us.

Comment: Col A is Date in 10min: 09.07.2015 00:00, 09.07.2015 00:10, and so on. Col B is Energy in kWh.

Answer (score 2):

*This will solve the issue:*

[image]

**N.B.**

- For better understanding in the shown example I've got the *SUM of 5 rows* (or bunch of 5 rows).
- Formula in Cell `E98`:

  `=SUM(OFFSET($B$98,(ROW()-98)*5,0,5,1))`
- Your Formula should be written like this.

`=SUM(OFFSET($B$98,(ROW()-98)*144,0,144,1))`

- If your data are in Range `A1:B1000` along with headers in Row 1 then use this Formula in Cell `D2`.

`=SUM(OFFSET($B$2,(ROW()-2)*144,0,144,1))`

*Adjust cell references in the formula  as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that uses `Index()` rather than `Offset()`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A$2:A$181411,1+144*(ROWS($1:1)-1)):INDEX(A$2:A$181411,ROWS($1:1)*144))
```

and copy downward.